# Как упорядочить массив по типам?

Tags: c#, сортировка

Существует массив из объектов-наследников класса `Car`: `PassengerCar`, `FreightCar` и `SpecializedFreightCar`.

Нужно упорядочить массив по типам наследников. К примеру, сначала идут объекты `PassengerCar`, затем `FreightCar`, потом `SpecializedFreightCar`.

`PassengerCar` и `FreightCar` наследуют черты класса `Car`.

`SpecializedFreightCar` наследует черты класса `FreightCar`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
array.OrderBy(e =>
{
    if (e is PassengerCar) return 0;
    if (e is FreightCar) return 1;
    //...
})
```

Но лучше добавить в классы свойство, типа такого:

```
public virtual int SortOrder => 0;
```

и сортировать по нему.

Comment: Второй вариант плох - потенциально он нарушает OCP. + непонятно, как быть, если в другом месте потребуется сортировка в другом порядке. Первый способ лучше, но если сортировка нужна в нескольких местах - надо вынести Comparer отдельно (как показано в моем ответе).

Comment: @АндрейNOP Если я переименую свойство на `SpecificTaskSordOrder`, тогда принцип OCP не нарушится :)

Answer (score 6):

Если сортировка может использоваться в нескольких местах, рекомендую написать Comparer, например:

```
class CarComparer : IComparer<Car>
{
    static Dictionary<Type, int> priorities = new Dictionary<Type, int>();
    static CarComparer()
    {
        priorities.Add(typeof(PassengerCar), 1);
        priorities.Add(typeof(FreightCar), 2);
        priorities.Add(typeof(SpecializedFreightCar), 3);
    }

    int PriorityFor(Type type)
    {
        priorities.TryGetValue(type, out int p);
        return p;
    }

    public int Compare(Car x, Car y)
    {
        int priorityX = PriorityFor(x.GetType());
        int priorityY = PriorityFor(y.GetType());
        return priorityX.CompareTo(priorityY);
    }
}
```

Пример использования:

```
Car[] cars =
{
    new SpecializedFreightCar(),
    new FreightCar(),
    new FreightCar(),
    new PassengerCar(),
    new SpecializedFreightCar()
};
Array.Sort(cars, new CarComparer());
Console.WriteLine(string.Join<Car>("\n", cars));
```

Код почти дословно скопирован из книги "Принципы, паттерны и методики гибкой разработки на языке C#" Роберт Мартин, Мика Мартин